# How to prove $(x+y)^2\leq 2(x^2+y^2)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, proof-verification

I want to prove 
$$(x+y)^2\leq 2(x^2+y^2)\tag 1
$$

I can prove this (I think) based on intuition, but not algebraically. My attempts as following.

**Attempt 1 (intuition):**

I have $(x+y)^2=x^2+2xy+y^2$. I take the RHS and write:
$$
x^2+2xy+y^2=x^2+2xy+y^2 \tag 2
$$
In the RHS I discard the term $2xy$ and multiply with 2, so:
$$
x^2+2xy+y^2=2(x^2+y^2) \tag 3
$$
And now I can (?) introduce an equality:
$$(x+y)^2\leq 2(x^2+y^2) \tag 4
$$

*Am I allowed to do this? Is it correct?*

**Attempt 2 (algebra):**

Start with $(x+y)^2=x^2+2xy+y^2$.

Subtract $-2xy$ and add $x^2$ and $y^2$ on both sides:

\begin{align}
(x+y)^2-2xy+x^2+y^2&=x^2+2xy+y^2-2xy+x^2+y^2 \tag 5\\\iff\\
(x+y)^2-2xy+x^2+y^2&=2x^2+2y^2 \tag 6
\end{align}
*Stuck, what have I missed here?*

Comment: Please remember that you can choose an aswer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 3):

$$x^2+2xy+y^2\leq 2x^2+2y^2\;\; ?$$
 $$ 0 \leq x^2-2xy+y^2 \;\;?$$
$$ 0\leq (x-y)^2 \;\;\checkmark$$

Comment: Is that a radical used as a checkmark o.o

Comment: Yeah, I can't write it. Can you help me with that

Comment: I think it's cute. But anyway https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132783/how-to-write-checkmark-in-latex

Comment: If you find this soultion please fell free to accept it.

Answer (score 2):

The standard way is

$$(x+y)^2\leq 2(x^2+y^2)\iff x^2+2xy+y^2\le 2x^2+2y^2$$$$\iff  x^2-2xy+y^2=(x-y)^2 \ge 0$$